# how to make required to an input field if field has default value using validate plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form which make required others fields if selected or filled any on them, I am using Validate plugin.

What I want is if input field has a default value like given `value="0.00"` its should not make others input fields required, only make required if manually filled.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>From Recognition Score</label>
    <input type="text" name="from_individual_recognition_score_3rd" class="form-control m2 validate[condRequired[recognize_1,recognize_3,recognize_4],min[1]]" id="recognize_2" maxlength="5" value='0.00'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks & Regards

Comment: That is precisely what the `placeholder` attribute is for.   Otherwise you have a value and the validation is satisfied.

Comment: *"its should not make others input fields required, only make required if manually filled."* - this sounds like grammatical gibberish.  Please explain better and show enough code to construct a demo.  If you're talking about multiple input fields, then show us.  Where is the validation code?  The `.validate()` method?

Answer (score 0):

> only make required if manually filled

That makes no sense whatsoever.  How can you make a field `required` if it's already filled out with something?  Only empty fields can be made `required`.  Once they contain a value, they are no longer "required" since the `required` rule of validation is fully satisfied.

Use the `placeholder` attribute because that is what it's for; to show a default or example value to the user.

```html
Showing the default value using placeholder attribute:

<input type="text" placeholder="0.00" name="from_individual_recognition_score_3rd" />
```

Otherwise, maybe you can [write a custom rule/method](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) that makes more sense for your project.  Since you've shown very little code in your OP, there is no way to know what would work here.